# Download dependencies from a maven repository using grunt

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, gruntjs

I want to access maven and download 1 dependencie that I have in a pom.xml

```
    <artifactId>id</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>lorep ipsum</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.whatever.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.cubeia.firebase.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-js-api</artifactId>
      <classifier>javascript</classifier>
      <type>js</type>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
```

Is there any plugin to access to a maven repository, or should I write it by node-js? I know there are plugins to deploy and realease to maven, but no for download dependencies.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you have a maven based project you can simply add the dependency as a dependency it will be downloaded automatically. If you like to do it explicit you can use the maven-dependency-plugin for such purposes.

Comment: This could me help to do a first approach, but I would like to download the dependencie, that is on a maven repository, using grunt or node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm downloading the dependencies from maven using a maven build that I call using "grunt-git"

```
shell: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    stdout: true
                },
                command: 'mvn clean install -f ./dependencies/pom.xml'                    
        }
```

I just run my mvn build, that just download the dependencies to the target folder I want.